# Flutter with Node Socket IO Working On Emulater but Not Working on Real Device

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, socket.io

serverside node socket.io = ^2.0.3

flutterSide flutter_socket_io: ^0.6.0

Flutter Side Code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutsocketchat/models/local/localMessage.dart';
import 'package:flutsocketchat/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutsocketchat/providers/local/localMessageStoreProvider.dart';
import 'package:flutsocketchat/screens/homePage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_socket_io/flutter_socket_io.dart';
import 'package:flutter_socket_io/socket_io_manager.dart';

class ChatFunctionsProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  final String currentUserID = HomePage.currentUSerId;
  final localMessageStorageProvider = LocalMessageStoreProvider();

  //Getter And Setter For Users
  List<User> _userList = [
    User("Sonu", "111"),
    User("Monu", "222"),
    User("Gonu", "333"),
    User("Tonu", "444"),
  ];

  List<User> get mates =>
      _userList.where((user) => user.id != currentUserID).toList();

  SocketIO socketIO;

  //Initialize Socket
  void initSocket() {
    socketIO = SocketIOManager().createSocketIO(
      'http://198.158.275.132:5050',
      '/',
      query: 'chatID=${HomePage.currentUSerId}',
    );

    socketIO.init();
//Receive Message Function
    socketIO.subscribe('receive_message', (jsonData) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(jsonData);
      localMessageStorageProvider.addMessageInStore(
        LocalMessage(
          receiver: data['receiverChatID'],
          text: data['content'],
          sender: data['senderChatID'],
        ),
      );
      notifyListeners();
    });

    socketIO.connect();
  }

  // Send Message Function
  void sendMessage(String text, String receiverChatID) {
    localMessageStorageProvider.addMessageInStore(LocalMessage(
      sender: currentUserID,
      text: text,
      receiver: receiverChatID,
    ));
    socketIO.sendMessage(
      'send_message',
      json.encode({
        'receiverChatID': receiverChatID,
        'senderChatID': currentUserID,
        'content': text,
      }),
    );
    notifyListeners();
  }

  destroySocket() {
    if (socketIO != null) {
      SocketIOManager().destroySocket(socketIO);
    }
  }

}
```

ServerSide Code

```
const app = require('express')()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Node Server is running. Yay!!")
})


io.on('connection', socket => {

    //Get the chatID of the user and join in a room of the same name
    let chatId = socket.handshake.query.chatID
    console.log(chatId +" is Online")

    // socket.on('createRoom', currentUserID =>{
    //     console.log(currentUserID +" is Online")
    // })

    //join The Room
    socket.join(chatId)

    //Leave the room if the user closes the socket
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socket.leave(chatId)
    })

    //Send message Event
    socket.on('send_message', message =>  {

        console.log(message)

        receiverChatID = message.receiverChatID
        senderChatID = message.senderChatID
        content = message.content

        //Send message to only that particular id
        socket.in(receiverChatID).emit('receive_message', {
            'content': content,
            'senderChatID': senderChatID,
            'receiverChatID': receiverChatID,
        })
    })
});

http.listen(5050, () => {
    console.log("Server is Running at port 5050")
})
```

This Code is Work Flawlessly in emulator and not working on real device...
Also there is no Error Log Showing....Just App is not Working like its not even connected to socket when we run it on real device..

Comment: Hello, did you get any error messages on your console? If so, post it.

Comment: Thats the  Problem bro...i cant get any error log...app is working flawlessly on emulater but not working on real device....

Comment: Alright. Can you include some relevant code samples so we can debug from here?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Comment: I Updated it in my Question..

Comment: There's nothing even when you run `adb logcat`?

Comment: Sorry bro..its new for me...How can i run that `adb logcat` ?